# MdiContainer form not opening

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-2.0, mdi, mdichild

I have two forms named `mdfi` and `form1`. I want to make `mdfi` form a `MdiContainer` by code from `form1`. I tried the following but the programs close when I run:

```
private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TopMost = false;
    Mdfi newMDIChild = new Mdfi();
    newMDIChild.IsMdiContainer = true;
    this.MdiParent = newMDIChild;
    newMDIChild.Show();
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to add the form during the Deactivate event()!

Comment: I am making a picture viewer look like Google picasa so , when the user click where ever in the screen it make a mdi form and the image fit in that ..

Comment: An MDI form lives inside the parent form. I'm not sure if that's what you want. Are you hitting the [X] button to close `form1` when this code gets called?

Comment: @JeffBridgman when my form1 deactivate i want to make my 'mdfi' form as  mdi parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the main window of your app into a child window has many side effects.  Winforms is forced to destroy the window because of the MdiParent assignment.  That's enough to get your Application.Run() call in the Main() method to complete and that's the end of your app.  You'll have to change that:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var main = new Form1();
        main.Show();
        Application.Run();
    }
```

And you have to make sure that you now terminate when the MDI parent is closed:

```
    private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.TopMost = false;
        var newMdiParent = new mdfi();
        newMdiParent.IsMdiContainer = true;
        this.MdiParent = newMdiParent;
        newMdiParent.FormClosed += (s, ea) => Application.Exit();
        newMdiParent.Show();
        this.Deactivate -= Form1_Deactivate;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
        if (this.MdiParent == null) Application.Exit();
    }
```